# How to cite inline in the form "name (year)"

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have been asked to present my inline citations as "name (year)" rather than "(name, year)" although I'm not sure what this type of citation is called. I have been using the `apacite` package so far for citations with bibtex. I would like some assistance to change the way this is presented and which packages to use, thank you.

Comment: It should be doable with the author-year citation style of `biblatex` (the parentheses for the year are missing, but it is easy to patch biblatex commands)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{doody}

\citep{doody}

\citet{doody}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

APA style calls the "Author (year)" form *narrative citation* whereas "(Author, year)" is called *parenthetical citation* (see e.g. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/parenthetical-versus-narrative).

In APA style narrative citations are used if the author(s) form a natural part of the flow of your sentence, e.g.

> Doody (1974) showed that ...

whereas parenthetical citations are used to give a reference if it does not form natural part of the sentence.

---

If you want to use standard `apacite` (without `natbib`/`natbibapa`), you can use `\citeA` for narrative citations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{doody}

\citeA{doody}

\citeNP{doody}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Doody, 1974) Doody (1974) Doody, 1974]